# If I download a shared Playstation game and then buy it, will I keep all my progress?

Tags: psn

If I downloaded a game off my friend's account on my PlayStation and then I decide to buy the exact game, would I lose all my progress on the game or not? I’m currently confused as to what to do, and I’m scared of buying it then downloading it and losing all my progress.

Answer (score 1):

PSN game saves are tied to the account you were signed in to when you play the game.  So if you download the game with your friend's account, switch to yours, and play it, your save created with your account will transfer.  Note, though, that you can only play the game if your friend has set the console this is done on as their primary console.